# Dynamic dependency injection in ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

In my app, there is one interface and two subclasses.
Two subclasses have been registered as services.
My question is how to control which one to get when i use them?

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public interface ITestDI
    {

    }

    public class TestDIClass1: ITestDI
    {
        public TestDIClass1()
        {

        }
    }

    public class TestDIClass2 : ITestDI
    {
        public TestDIClass2()
        {

        }
    }

    ITestDI td;

    public HomeController(ITestDI _td)
    {
        this.td = _td; // how to control which ITestDI implementation will injected with constructor injection? With the configuration below, always get TestDIClass2.
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddScoped<ITestDI, TestDIClass1>();
services.AddScoped<ITestDI, TestDIClass2>(); // it seems like TestDIClass2 has overwrited the TestDIClass1.
```

Comment: The idea here is that your code depends on an interface and not a concrete implementation. If your code only works with one service or the other, they should probably have different interfaces.

Comment: How do you call HomeController(ITestDI _td)?

Comment: For `public HomeController(ITestDI _td)`, what is the logic to decide which instance to return?

Comment: how to register a interface with two implementation ?

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible and doesn't even make sense. Perhaps you should try explaining WHY you want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options.

First, you can abandon Auto-Wiring and make the registration using a delegate, as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<TestDIClass1>();    
services.AddScoped<TestDIClass2>();

services.AddTransient<HomeController>(c => new HomeController(
    _td: c.GetRequiredService<TestDIClass2>());
```

Here you register both `ITestDI` by their concrete type. This allows the delegate for `HomeController` to request a specific implementation using `GetRequiredService<T>`.

Hand-wiring such object, however, can become cumbersome, especially when `HomeController` contains more dependencies, because it would require you to resolve *all* dependencies manually. So instead, you can make use of MS.DI's `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` class. It implements a simplified form of MS.DI's Auto-Wiring abilities. The following snippet shows this:

```
services.AddScoped<TestDIClass1>();    
services.AddScoped<TestDIClass2>();

services.AddTransient<HomeController>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<HomeController>(
        c,                                             
        new object[]                                   
        {                                              
            c.GetRequiredService<TestDIClass2>(),         
        }));
```

In this example, `HomeController` is requested from `ActivatorUtilities`. The `CreateInstance` call is supplied an `IServiceProvider` instance (the `c` argument) and an array of instances to inject into `HomeController`'s constructor. `ActivatorUtilities` will match the supplied objects to `HomeController`'s constructor arguments and will resolve all missing arguments from the provided `IServiceProvider`.

The use of `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` allows your registration to stay unchanged, even if new arguments are added to `HomeController`'s constructor, for instance:

```
public HomeController(
    ILogger logger,          // new argument added
    ITestDI td,
    IProductService service  // another argument added
)
```

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` will figure out that the resolved `TestDIClass2` can be mapped to the `td` constructor argument, and it will resolve `ILogger` and `IProductService` from the `IServiceProvider`.

There are other options available, but these are in your case probably the most likely options, in case you don't want to change your design.

This information is an condensed version of the book [Dependency Injection Principles. Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl). That contains a complete chapter on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI) and about 16 pages on *Working with multiple components*.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to register concrete class.

```
public HomeController(TestDIClass2 _td)
{
    this.td = _td; //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have registered more than one instances, you have to ask Dependency Injection framework for an `IEnumerable<ITestDI> _testDis;`

and then you have to iterate trough it

```
foreach(var instance in _testDis)
{
    instance.YourMethod();
}
```